# Unable to kill remote processes with ssh

Tags: shell, ssh, process, kill

I need to kill remote processes with a shell script as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

ip="172.24.63.41"
user="mag"
timeout 10s ssh -q $user@$ip exit
if [ $? -eq 124 ]
then
    echo "can not connect to $ip, timeout out."
else
    echo "connected, executing commands"
    scp a.txt $user@$ip://home/mag
    ssh -o ConnectTimeout=10 $user@$ip > /dev/null 2>&1 << remoteCmd

    touch b.txt
    jobPid=`jps -l | grep jobserver | awk '{print $1}'`
    if [ ! $jobPid == "" ]; then
        kill -9 $jobPid
    fi
    exit

remoteCmd

echo "commands executed."
fi
```

After executed it I found the scp and touch clauses had been executed, but the kill clause had not been executed successful and the process is still there. If I run clauses from "jobPid= ..." to "fi" on remote machine the process can be killed. How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I put a script on the remote machine which can find and kill the process, then I ran the script on local machine which execute the script on the remote machine with ssh. The script is as follows:

Local script:

```
#!/bin/bash
ip="172.24.63.41"
user="mag"

timeout 10s ssh -q $user@$ip exit
if [ $? -eq 124 ]
then
    echo "can not connect to $ip, timeout out."
else
    echo "connected, executing commands"
    ssh -q $user@$ip "/home/mag/local.sh"
    echo "commands executed."
fi
```

remote script:

```
#!/bin/bash
jobPid=`jps -l | grep jobserver | awk '{print $1}'`
if [ ! $jobPid == "" ]; then
    kill -9 $jobPid
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script needs root access (WHICH IS NEVER A GOOD IDEA). Or make sure your program which is running, is running under your webuser/group

Comment: I have modify the user to "root" and run the script. It still can not kill the process. But the scp and touch clauses is stll working. Would you please give me any other suggestions? By the way, what does the webuser/group means? thank you in advance.